# "I wasn't meant to do" in the future

Tags: conditional-constructions, future-tense

Is the usage "I wasn't meant to do" correct when we speak about something we didn't plan to do? What if the action didn't happen?

- Hey, don't touch that bottle.
- I wasn't meant to touch it.

Comment: *I didn't mean to touch it* is the normal way of putting it. In other words, it was an accident.

Comment: What if it didn't happen.

Comment: I don't intend to touch it.  I don't mean to touch it. My intention was not to touch it.

Comment: "Why did you not pick up the package?" "It was not meant for me." We would understand it, but it is not common usage. The most common would be. "Why didn't you get married?" "It was not meant to be." Still not common.

Comment: If you didn't touch it, and you weren't trying to, the most common thing to say would probably be *"I wasn't trying to touch it."*  To say "I didn't mean to touch it" implies that you did touch it, but by accident.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're confusing two expressions:

> I didn't mean to touch it

and

> It wasn't meant to be touched.

The first expresses lack of intention, and implies accidental contact.  The second is a passive *description* of the characteristic of something.

If you instead want to express that you didn't touch something, and had no intention to do so, you would say:

> I wasn't going to touch it.